React Native Android version crashes after installing react-native-google-mobile-ads
I copied exactly the same code from the official documentation, but the app is crashing and unable to start. Here is my code


    import React from 'react';
import { BannerAd, BannerAdSize, TestIds } from 'react-native-google-mobile-ads';

const adUnitId = __DEV__ ? TestIds.ADAPTIVE_BANNER : 'i have my app id here';

export const App =()=> {
  return (
    <BannerAd
      unitId={adUnitId}
      size={BannerAdSize.ANCHORED_ADAPTIVE_BANNER}
      requestOptions={{
        networkExtras: {
          collapsible: 'bottom',
        },
      }}
    />
  );
}



and in index.js I have the following


/**
 * @format
 */

import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import mobileAds from 'react-native-google-mobile-ads';
mobileAds()
.initialize()
.then(() => console.log('Ads initialized'))
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);



and the error looks like the following. I copied this from the console and the app is not able to start. its crashing. I tried rebuilding, clearing cache and the like but that doesn't solved the issue. any help please?


FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
   > An issue was found when checking AAR metadata:
     
       1.  Dependency 'androidx.webkit:webkit:1.11.0-alpha02' requires libraries and applications that
           depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
           Android APIs.
     
           :app is currently compiled against android-33.
     
           Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
           plugin 7.3.1 is 33.
     
           Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
           plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
           compileSdkVerion of at least 34.
     
           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
           targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
           minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
           on).

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s

Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
   > An issue was found when checking AAR metadata:
     
       1.  Dependency 'androidx.webkit:webkit:1.11.0-alpha02' requires libraries and applications that
           depend on it to compile against version 34 or later of the
           Android APIs.
     
           :app is currently compiled against android-33.
     
           Also, the maximum recommended compile SDK version for Android Gradle
           plugin 7.3.1 is 33.
     
           Recommended action: Update this project's version of the Android Gradle
           plugin to one that supports 34, then update this project to use
           compileSdkVerion of at least 34.
     
           Note that updating a library or application's compileSdkVersion (which
           allows newer APIs to be used) can be done separately from updating
           targetSdkVersion (which opts the app in to new runtime behavior) and
           minSdkVersion (which determines which devices the app can be installed
           on).

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s

    at makeError (/Users/***/Desktop/data/mymobileprojects/examet/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Users/***/Desktop/data/mymobileprojects/examet/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/***/Desktop/data/mymobileprojects/examet/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/***/Desktop/data/mymobileprojects/examet/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:108:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.



